# Templated virtual method

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have several models, which all have the same interface with the same methods, which **must** be templated:

```
template <typename T>
struct BaseModel {

  template <typename T> inline void
    method1(const T& x, const T& y, T& xx, T& yy) const;

  template <typename T> inline void
    method2(const T& x, const T& y, T& xx, T& yy) const;

};


struct ImplModel1 : public BaseModel<T> {

  template <typename T> inline void
    method1(const T& x, const T& y, T& xx, T& yy) const {
        ...
    }

  template <typename T> inline void
    method2(const T& x, const T& y, T& xx, T& yy) const {
        ...
    }

};
```

At the same time I want to be able to pass derived models to functions:

```
dynamic_function(BaseModel& model, ...) {
    // do something with one of the derived models
    model.method1<double>(...);
    model.method1<ObjectXY>(...);
    model.method2<int>(...);
    ...
}

dynamic_function(ImplModel1(), ...)
dynamic_function(ImplModel2(), ...)
```

Actually, the structs should just serve as containers for the functions and no object-oriented features of it will be used at all. I just want to save and pass these templated functions in bunch. Accessing the functions should be fast (which is why I inlined them).

Is this possible at all? I am also open to any other design recommendation.

Comment: I have to say this isn't easy to follow at all; `BaseModel` has an unused type T from the template parameter. ImplModel1` has no template decl, but is somehow inventing one to pass as the (unused) parameter to `BaseModel<T>`. Perhaps explaining the *problem* you're trying to solve in better detail would help, because right now this has the faint aroma of an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: is there a reason why dynamic_function() can't be also a template?

Comment: **must** be templated?  Hmmm...